# Postman: Query body values as number

Tags: php, json, postman

In Postman, is there a way to send the value of **parent1[child]** as a *number* rather than a *string*?
[image: postman query body x-www-form-urlencoded]

I am aware that I could simply do it like this:
[image: postman query body raw JSON]

However, my specific case requires it to be sent as **x-www-form-urlencoded**.

Comment: Are you sure the the request allowed json ? ( if yes, maybe a comma is missing)

Comment: Which version of the all are you using, seems very old.

Comment: @Traian GEICU. I think so, yes. As for the missing comma, don't mind the typo on the 2nd screenshot.

Comment: @Danny Dainton Postman v5.5.5

Comment: @kbien Why number? Any specific reason?

Comment: @vivek_23 I have to pass it to a third party API which requires that property to be a number, more specifically an int32.

Comment: With `x-www-form-urlencoded`, all data will be sent in the same way: `foo=bar&bar=1` (that's how the data is sent in the request body). You, on the caller side, can't define what should be interpreted as a string or a number, you can only set a value. It's up to the receiver to interpret the data they get.

Comment: @kbien I presume form url enocded data sent over a network in a serialized format would always be a string. It's weird from the third party API to not convert string to int on their own.

Comment: I was trying to simulate a JQuery ajax request (via postman) sent to my app's API (written in PHP)--albeit a minimal recreation. It then sends a request (via cURL) to the third party API along with some of the data provided by the ajax request. Side note, my app's API is acting like a middle-man here since it holds the request authentication key(s) for accessing the third party API. Perhaps I should just type-cast the specific data in my API before sending it to the third party API. Anyway, I'm still familarizing myself with the third party API.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to send the `POST` body as JSON (`application/json`), you need to use the "raw" or "binary" option. "x-www-form-urlencoded" (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) is a different data format that doesn't distinguish between strings and numbers. You'll have to parse the data out by hand on the other end if you want to use `x-www-form-urlencoded`. That is, the *receiving end* will have to know whether a field should contain text or numeric data and handle it accordingly. If you need to make this determination on the *sending side*, you should not plan to use `x-www-form-urlencoded` because it doesn't support that distinction.

Your top example is sending this `POST` body:

```
parent1[child]=200&parent2[child]=Hello%20World
```

Your bottom example is sending this completely different `POST` body:

```
{
    "parent1": {
        "child": 200
    },
    "parent2": {
        "child": "Hello World"
    }
}
```